# Block python's atexit during a crash?

Tags: python, flask

I have a python script I've written which uses atexit.register() to run a function to persist a list of dictionaries when the program exits.  However, this code is also running when the script exits due to a crash or runtime error.  Usually, this results in the data becoming corrupted.

Is there any way to block it from running when the program exits abnormally?

EDIT: To clarify, this involves a program using flask, and I'm trying to prevent the data persistence code from running on an exit that results from an error being raised.

Comment: Please shed light on "crash" , "runtime error", "abnormally"

Comment: Why use `atexit()` for this? Just write the data at the end of the program.

Comment: It doesn't exit when it reaches the end of the program, it's using the flask framework and the call to app.run() is at the end.  It only exits when I press CTRL-C on the command line.

Comment: 1_CR: By crash or runtime error, I mean the program is shutdown because an error was raised.

Comment: @ZauberParacelsus: You mean Flask shuts down your application, or Flask itself shuts down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to use `atexit` with Flask. You want to use [Flask signals.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/signals/) It sounds like you are specifically looking for the `request_finished` signal.

```
from flask import request_finished
def request_finished_handler(sender, response, **extra):
    sender.logger.debug('Request context is about to close down.  '
                        'Response: %s', response)
    # do some fancy storage stuff.

request_finished.connect(request_finished_handler, app)
```

The benefit of `request_finished` is that it only fires after a successful response. That means that so long as there isn't an error in another signal, you should be good.

Comment: This answer doesn't exactly do what I had been asking for, it does something even better than I wanted and removes the need to persist data when the program closes.  It actually should solve a few other problems I was concerned about.

Answer (score 3):

One way:  at global level in main program:

```
abormal_termination = False

def your_cleanup_function():
    # Add next two lines at the top
    if abnormal_termination:
        return

# ...
# At end of main program:
try:
    # your original code goes here
except Exception:  # replace according to what *you* consider "abnormal"
    abnormal_termination = True # stop atexit handler
```

Not pretty, but straightforward ;-)

Comment: Well, to clarify a little, this is a program using the flask framework.  Once it reaches app.run(), it continues indefinitely until the program exits, and generally that's only if I hit CTRL-C on the command line to force an exit.  I have to wonder if that is treated as an abnormal exit, though...

Comment: That's not "a little", that's an entirely different universe ;-)  Sorry, I don't know anything about `flask`.  Add a `flask` tag to this question, and spell out at the top that you have no control over anything after `flask` starts running your code forever?